# 2D Non-OpenGL Game : ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm building a very simple iOS game that doesn't require any `OpenGL`; I'd like to stick with Core Graphics & Core Animation.

It seems as though I need two types of ViewControllers: Basic VCs for navigating between menu screens (ie. Settings, Main Menu, Level Select, etc.), and Gameplay VCs for managing all my `UIViews` and `CALayers`.

What's a good way to manage/exchange these Views & VCs to preserve performance? Is it best practice to have one hierarchy of VCs like a traditional `UINavigationController`-based app, covering the NavBar when I'm displaying a Game VC? Or instead should I be removing all other ViewControllers from the stack when I enter "game mode", and setting it as my `window.rootViewController` property? Any alternatives / downsides to continually resetting `window.rootViewController`?

My gut tells me the latter is better on resources+performance, but it seems heavy handed.  Any advice + direction here would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Moderators - I asked this over at the programmers site as it was "related to high level coding concepts", thought I think it's specific enough to live here as well. Happy to move + edit if necessary. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/111744/simple-ios-game-view-controllers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably make the Game VC the rootViewController, and present the game selection as modal view controller on top of that controller. You can do that without animating at the beginning of the application. When the user is done with the setup, dismiss the view controller.